# How to see which PHP script is consuming the most memory?

Tags: linux, memory, php

I'm trying to see which of my PHP scripts uses the most memory and CPU when it's viewed by a browser. I can only find methods like `top` and `free` that show per-process usage, but I need it narrowed down for a particular PHP script. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see how much memory a particular PHP script uses you can use the `memory_get_usage` function listed [here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.memory-get-usage.php).

Answer (score -2):

The amount of memory a file consumes within RAM is the same as the file size on the disk. If your file is 1.5 MB, it will consume no more and no less than 1.5 MB in RAM.

A file does not use the CPU. Only running processes like you see when running top.

Comment: This is not correct. A small PHP script can create very large arrays that require lots of RAM.